# Which Bluetooth Module can I use with Arduino Micro/Mini?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-micro, arduino-mini

I need to use a Bluetooth module with an Arduino Micro/Mini.

Please suggest which one would be the best, HC 05/06, or any other?

Comment: It depends on what you want the module to do. For just serial communication the HC modules are fine. For anything more complex you may want to look at BLE.

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Answer (score 2):

I have had good results using the [Bluefruit LE UART Friend](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2479) module from Adafruit with a 32u4 micro Arduino type module, there are only a few pins to connect up to get things going (do remember to follow the instructions to pull the CTS pin to ground).

As per the previous answer it really does depend on what you want to do with it - but this module does Low Energy, can be configured as a "Beacon" and there is a companion App for Android/iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Do you require slaves or masters?

Both modules are actually the same, it is just the firmware that is different, and in turn that changes how they use the pins. HC05 can be both Master and Slave, and has a full set of AT commands, whereas HC06 can only be a slave, and has a more limited set of AT commands at its disposal.

Otherwise, for low power projects, then BLE modules, such as HC-10 or HC-11 might be worth considering.

Really, it all depends on what you want to do with them, what is the overall project? You could get away with one HC-05 and one HC-06, but it is really task dependant. It is probably worth you having a read up of some articles on the web, and looking at some example projects to see other people's configurations. This will hopefully help you to see what you actually require for your project.

FWIW, I looked into this a few months back and wrote a short blog, [BlueMoon](https://gr33nonline.wordpress.com/2015/08/13/blue-moon/), on it, which contains some example projects and links to video tutorials - this may help give you an insight...